# PHP array detect if it contains unique value

Tags: php, arrays

I have some PHP arrays that looks like this...

```
$cars1 = array("Volvo", "Volvo", "Volvo");
$cars2 = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$cars3 = array("Volvo");
$cars4 = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Volvo");
$cars5 = array("BMW", "Toyota");
```

I need to detect when an array contains all Volvo's or only one Volvo on it's own.  So in the examples above only $cars1 and $cars3 would pass.

Anyone have a similar example I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're proably looking for something like [this](https://repl.it/DqW7)

```
function arrayEq($array,$val)
{
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        if($item != $val)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$cars1 = array("Volvo", "Volvo", "Volvo");
$cars2 = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$cars3 = array("Volvo");
$cars4 = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Volvo");
$cars5 = array("BMW", "Toyota");

var_dump(arrayEq($cars1,"Volvo"));
var_dump(arrayEq($cars2,"Volvo"));
var_dump(arrayEq($cars3,"Volvo"));
var_dump(arrayEq($cars4,"Volvo"));
var_dump(arrayEq($cars5,"Volvo"));
```

what the function does is loops though the passed array with a for each and with each item in the array it compares it to the comparing value we passed in.

if even one item in the array doesn't match the comapring value we return false. this breaks out of the loop as well. if the loop can goes all the way though then we know that all the values are the same and return true

note that this is case sensitive ss `"Volvo" != "volvo"` but you can fix this with something like [`strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) or [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function followed by a simple `if` condition, like this:

```
$cars1 = array("Volvo", "Volvo", "Volvo");
$car = array_unique($cars1);

if(count($car) == 1 && $car[0] == 'Volvo'){
    // the condition has passed
    // Only $cars1 and $cars3 would get through this if condition
}

// like this, apply the same procedure for other arrays
```